# Java Object streams to libGDX project

Tags: java, libgdx, stream, classnotfoundexception

i did try to test some stuff about Client/server communication in Java because i wanted to build a game with a client/server architecture.

So i read some articles and so on... it all worked till i tried to use the same classes and methods in a libGDX project client and the other as server was still the original java project.

than the fun started and i got class not found exceptions on the server side when the server where trying to read the object.

after that i tried to build client and server both as libGDX projects.
still the same error.

the serve:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;


public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 8800;
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("raedy");
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println(clientSocket+"verbunden!");
                Worker worker = new Worker(clientSocket);
                worker.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}



package com.mygdx.game;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Worker extends Thread{

    private Socket clientSocket;

    public  Worker(Socket clientsocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientsocket;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("worker started");
        try {
            ObjectInputStream in= new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            Object obj = (Object) in.readObject();
            if(obj instanceof Message) {
            Message msg= (Message) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("Client said: "+msg.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("input auf"+clientSocket.getLocalPort());
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(new Message("Hello there!"));
            System.out.println("output auf"+clientSocket.getPort());
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

package com.mygdx.game;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Message implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String message;

    public Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }
}
```

the client has the the same Message class and this:

```
package com.mygdx.game.desktop;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        int port = 8800;
        try {
            System.out.println("hello there!");
            Socket client = new  Socket("localhost", port );
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(new Message("ich bin der client"));
            System.err.println(client.getPort());

            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            Message msg= (Message) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("Server said: "+msg.getMessage());
            System.out.println(client.getLocalPort());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```

**so my question is why does the same code work in normal java but when i build the same as a libGDX project and try the code there it doesn't work?**

yes the message class is only for testing how a serializable object is transferred.
Later i want to send game commands via the object stream.

ps: you made it till the end! thank you :D

pps: the first try in java was without

```
Object obj = (Object) in.readObject();
            if(obj instanceof Message)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would really recommend you to use [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) instead of writing all the stuff from scratch yourself. It does exactly what you are trying to achieve, is mature and well tested with libGDX.